# Scrapy - Get spider variables inside DOWNLOAD MIDDLEWARE __init__

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working on a Scrapy project, on which I wrote a DOWNLOADER MIDDLEWARE to avoid making requests to URLs that are already on the database.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'imobotS.utilities.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
   'imobotS.utilities.DupFilterMiddleware': 500,
   'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
}
```

The idea is to connect and load on **__init__** a distinct list of all the urls currently stored on DB, and raise IgnoreRequests if the scraped item is already on DB.

```
class DuplicateFilterMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 12345)
        self.db = connection['my_db']
        self.db.authenticate('scott', '*****')

        self.url_set = self.db.ad.find({'site': 'WEBSITE_NAME'}).distinct('url')

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        print "%s - process Request URL: %s" % (spider._site_name, request.url)
        if request.url in self.url_set:
            raise IgnoreRequest("Duplicate --db-- item found: %s" % request.url)
        else:
            return None
```

So, as I want to restrict the url_list defined on init by WEBSITE_NAME, is there a way to identify the current spider name inside the Download Middleware **__init__** method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the fetching of the url set under `process_request` and just check if you have previously fetched it.

```
class DuplicateFilterMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 12345)
        self.db = connection['my_db']
        self.db.authenticate('scott', '*****')

        self.url_sets = {}

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if not self.url_sets.get(spider._site_name):
            self.url_sets[spider._site_name] = self.db.ad.find({'site': spider._site_name}).distinct('url')

        print "%s - process Request URL: %s" % (spider._site_name, request.url)
        if request.url in self.url_sets[spider._site_name]:
            raise IgnoreRequest("Duplicate --db-- item found: %s" % request.url)
        else:
            return None
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on what [@Ahsan Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12123215/ahsan-roy) said above, you don't have to use the signals API (at least in Scrapy 2.4.0):

From the `from_crawler` method, you have access to the spider (with its name) as well as all the other spider settings. You can use this to pass any argument you want into the constructor of your middleware class (i.e. `__init__`):

```
class DuplicateFilterMiddleware(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        """This method is called by Scrapy and needs to return an instance of the middleware"""
        return cls(crawler.spider, crawler.settings)

    def __init__(self, spider, settings):
        self.spider_name = spider.name
        self.settings = settings

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        print("spider {s} is processing stuff".format(s=self.spider_name))
        return None  # keep processing normally
```

Comment: The best explanation I've read! amazing! voted up

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access the spider name, in your middleware by defining `from_crawler` class method and connect a spider open signal to a function `spider_opened`. Than you can save the spider name in your middleware class.

```
from scrapy import signals

def __init__(self, crawler):
    self.crawler = crawler
    self.spider_name = None
    return

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    ext = cls(crawler)
    # connect the middleware object to signals
    crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
    # return the middleware object
    return ext

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    self.spider_name = spider.name
```

For more information on signals check [Signals](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/signals.html#topics-signals)